# Window Service equivalent for OnHandleCreated (from C#)

Tags: c#, windows, console-application

**Is there any equivalent for OnHandleCreated  & WndProc functions for a Window Service similar to the one in C# for a form?**

I need to implement  WatchBP SDK(USB Library) for **window Service that works with WebSocket** to get data from **from the device to Web UI**.

in SDK below methods need to implement but these methods not getting called in Window Service so notification not received from Device to window service.

```
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        this.watchBPOfficeHid.RegisterHandle(this.Handle);
        
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        this.watchBPOfficeHid.ParseMessages(ref m);
    }
```

although I inherit Window service class from **System.Windows.Forms.Form**
but above method not getting called.

In WinForms we could use OnHandleCreated to get the handle as soon as it is created. Is it any alternative for this in window service?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is no windows form handle in a windows service, which is why there is no `OnHandleCreated` and there are no window which is why there is no `WndProc` Why does this library need them? can you supply null?

Comment: You "*maybe*" able to create a form however, even though you cannot show it. Though my spidey senses tell me that what ever reason this library needs form handles will likely render it useless (but who knows)

Comment: @TheGeneral thanks for the reply, I although inherit my class with System.Windows.Forms.Form even though OnHandleCreated & WndProc functions not getting called. I need an alternative solution or suggestion if you have.